# docker-compose: no gunicorn when trying "up" container

Tags: django, docker, gunicorn, digital-ocean, docker-compose

I'm facing with issue when I try to "up" my container on DigitalOcean env. I have **Ubuntu Docker 1.7.1 on 14.04** as env droplet. There is the next error.

`mysite  | ./docker-entrypoint: line 8: exec: gunicorn: not found`

This is my Dockerfile where I tried to add gunicorn setup by (apt-get, pip). Sadly but it doesn't work I have the same issue with missed gunicorn module.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:2.7.7

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN apt-get -y install libpango1.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app

VOLUME /usr/src/app/venv
VOLUME /usr/src/app/node_modules
VOLUME /usr/src/app/static

ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint"]
```

Additionally I tried to add gunicorn setup to the entry point file which also didn't work there is "no gunicorn module" error still. I guess it wasn't a great idea to add it here but anyway I've checked.

**Docker entry point**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [[ -e venv/bin/activate ]]; then
    source venv/bin/activate
fi

exec "$@"
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
source:
  extends:
    file: docker-compose-common.yml
    service: prod
  build: .
  command: bin/install

redis:
  image: redis:latest
  command: redis-server --appendonly yes

mysite:
  extends:
    file: docker-compose-common.yml
    service: prod
  image: mysitecatalogweb_source
  volumes_from:
    - source
  environment:
    - SITE_ID=1
  command: gunicorn -k gevent -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --access-logfile - --error-logfile - mysite.wsgi
```

**docker-compose-common.yml**

```
dev:
  environment:
    - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
    - ENV=DEV
    - POSTGRES_HOST=host
    - POSTGRES_USER=user
  env_file: dev.env

prod:
  environment:
    - ENV=PROD
  env_file: prod.env
```

Maybe I need to add gunicorn setup to the bin/install directly (which should be called from *source* task) but this is also can be found in the requirements.txt **EDITED:** I've tried to add gunicorn here and it is still
`mysite  | ./docker-entrypoint: line 8: exec: gunicorn: not found`

**bin/install**

```
set -e

pip install virtualenv
if [[ ! -e venv/bin/activate ]]; then
  virtualenv venv
  source venv/bin/activate
fi

pip install -r requirements.txt

mkdir -p static/js
npm install
npm run browserify
```

Also check my requirements.txt
https://gist.github.com/alexnodejs/3789b4eb7621687e010b

Maybe someone already bumped with similar issue with unicorn?
Please advise where I should dig.

Comment: In the `mysite` service, you are using the image of the `source` service... I've never seen this kind of configuration. What is the reason to do that? You should be able to install gunicorn using `RUN pip install gunicorn` in the Dockerfile. Sorry if it is a silly question, but did you run `docker-compose build` before to use `docker-compose up`?

Comment: Alexis thanks for response, the reason of using _source_ service it's that I actually have several sites in one django project (container) and source service helps to build them (just shares volumes). And yes I run `docker-compose -f docker-compose-prod.yml build` before `up`

Comment: Also I'll try again to add `RUN pip install gunicorn` to the Docker file and rebuild the project, maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: Try to rethink the whole problem. Using venv inside container is unnecessary as you are already inside isolated environment but lower level and maybe it is the reason.

Comment: @AlexisN-o `docker-compose build` fixed it for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem I see is that you're using `image: mysitecatalogweb_source` for your `mysite` service, and expecting that to include the committed result of running `bin/install`, which wasn't actually committed to the `mysitecatalogweb_source` image -- it's sitting in a container instead, so the virtualenv was never created in the second `mysite` container, and is thus not activated and `gunicorn` is not available.  From just the snippet here, it appears that you ought to add `RUN bin/install` to your `Dockerfile` so that the virtualenv is set up before the attempt to use it.