# docker-compose conflicts with Dokerfile entry-point script

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a Docker image with my Django application, but unfortunately I'm getting troubles trying to run my entrypoint script.

Docker exits eith code error 127 and display the following message:

> /docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*

You find below the respective configuration files:

**Dockerfile**

```bash
FROM python:2.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir -p /web/src
ADD . /web/src
WORKDIR /web/src
RUN pip install -U pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt -U
RUN chmod u+x docker-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

**docker-entrypoint.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/bash
python manage.py migrate                  
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput  

touch /srv/logs/gunicorn.log
touch /srv/logs/access.log
tail -n 0 -f /srv/logs/*.log &

echo Starting Gunicorn...
exec gunicorn config.wsgi:application \
    --name django_server \
    --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 \
    --workers 3 \
    --log-level=info \
    --log-file=/srv/logs/gunicorn.log \
    --access-logfile=/srv/logs/access.log \
    "$@"
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```bash
version: '2.0'
services:
  db:
    container_name: db_server
    image: postgres
  web:
    container_name: django_server
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/web/src
    environment:
      - SECRET_KEY=k3jghf1jk%$JH^1GJH5@YUTR@!MBMB<5=7DXXG)JHSX=
      - PGDATABASE=postgres
      - PGUSER=postgres
      - PGPASSWORD=''
      - PGHOST=db
      - DJANGO_ENV=development
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - db
```

Comment: What OS are you using? Is this in a vm? What command are you running to create the image?

Comment: OS: Ubuntu 14.04, 
Command: docker-compose build

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want to do `docker build .` ?

Comment: When I `run docker build .` , the build pass but when I run `docker-compose up` to run the project it executes the entry script greatly but doesn't recognize gunicorn despite I can see in the build log that is installed. I get : `gunicorn: command not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reproducing the problem locally: `docker build .` build the image successfully, but when trying to start the image using `docker-compose up` I got the following error `exec: gunicorn: not found` as the OP mentioned above. Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31541581/docker-compose-no-gunicorn-when-trying-up-container) I could solve the problem running `docker-compose build`. So to sum up the 3 following commands should solve the problem:

1. `docker build .`
2. `docker-compose build`
3. `docker-compose up`

Despite this solves the problem for me I'm still confused here, why do I need to run build twice. I mean it should be something wrong somewhere, because as I far as I have understood, `docker-compose build`  should do the same work as `docker build .`.